# Parsing Data from A JSON file with python and checking it

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that just has this:

```
 {
  "jeff": {

   }
 }
```

I would like to check if i enter the name jeff in my input it will just print 123
I have tried it this way in python:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('users.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print("Hi, would you like to  sign up or login?")
print("Type Login for login and Signup to signup")

option= input()

if option == "Login":
    unameEntry = input("Please Enter Your Username")
    if unameEntry == data[unameEntry] :
        print("123")
```

but it does not find it i have looked around on google and have strougled to find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is wrong

When you access the value in your dictionary with:

```
data[unameEntry]
```

the dictionary returns you the value at `data[unameEntry]`. Suppose that, as you have set in your example, the user types in `"jeff"`: following your example the dictionary will return the corresponding value, in your example an empty dictionary.

Therefore your if is actually doing:

```
"jeff" == {}
```

that is clearly `False`.

### How to fix it

Most probably you want to check if the user is a key in the dictionary. You can do so by using the `in` operator:

```
unameEntry in data
```

#### Edited code

Since here we do not have access to your `users.json` file, let's include the dictionary in the code. Also, to detect if errors are found within the input handling, I'll through in a couple of asserts and expand the conditions tree:

```
data = {
    "jeff": {}
}

print("Hi, would you like to  sign up or login?")
print("Type Login for login and Signup to signup")

option= input()

assert option == "Login"

if option == "Login":
    unameEntry = input("Please Enter Your Username")
    assert unameEntry == "jeff"
    if unameEntry in data:
        print("Welcome %s!" % unameEntry)
    else:
        print("Username %s does not exist" % unameEntry)
```

Comment: i changed it to this

Comment: if unameEntry in data :
        print("123")

Comment: I have edited the code to help you debugging further. How does it do now?

Comment: Hi, would you like to  sign up or login? Type Login for login and Signup to signup Login Please Enter Your Usernamejeff Username jeff does not exist ] >>>

Comment: I have added another assert, does it throw the exception now?

Comment: because eventually the JSON file needs to be written to as well

Comment: If the `json` looks like the given dictionary, which you can verify for example by running `data.keys()` to check out which keys the dictionary holds, it should be completely indifferent.

Answer (score 0):

Made a few tweaks to what you have, and added some comments for detail. Here's what the Python would look like:

```
# Python3
import json


# Load json file one-liner
file_json = json.load(open("test.json", "r"))

# Since options can only be signup/login, santize them
option = input("Type Login for login and Signup to signup: ").strip().lower()
if option == "login":
    # Get name entry and strip it of whitespace
    name_entry = input("Please Enter Your Username: ").strip()
    # Use .get() on file_json dict() object, with a default option
    # of None. However, with this you actually have to add data to 
    # your JSON and not just a empty field
    if file_json.get(name_entry, None):
        print("123")
    else:
        print("Name: {}, not found".format(name_entry))
else:
    print("unrecognized option: {}".format(option))
```

And here's what the test JSON should look like:

```
{
    "jeff": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Notice how I've added a default value to `"jeff"`. Else, doing a lookup will always return nothing when you've got `{ }` as `"jeff"`'s value